# Trigger jQuery 'tapout' event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently using the following jQuery event:

```
$('.owl-item').on("taphold",function(){
  // Do something
}
```

So basically when an element with the class of `.owl-item` is tapped and held it will trigger this event.

When the user stops the tap hold e.g finger on the mobile device is no longer placed on the `.owl-item` element I would like to trigger another event.

I'm just wondering if there is any other events that can tell when a `taphold` event is no longer taking place and has ended?

Like so:

```
$('.owl-item').on("tapout",function(){
  // The element is no longer being held
}
```

Comment: `mousedown` => mark time start, `mouseup` => mark time end => if bigger than threshold => `taphold`. Map mouse events to touch events or use some plugin for that

Answer (score 0):

There is no **tapout** event for jQuery.

Instead try writing your required code under **touchend**.

```
$('.owl-item').on('touchend', function(event, ui) {
  console.log('Triggered touchend Event: '+event.type); 
});
```